# Can IF-Match be used to conditionally update a property, not ETAG?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, etag

In Azure Table, can I use the IF-Match tag when Merging to conditionally update a value on something other than ETAG?

Specifically, suppose I have an object like this

```
public class Person : TableServiceEntity
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Age {get;set}

public DateTime LockDate {get;set;}

}
```

Suppose I want to merge or update the object conditionally on the presence or comparison of the "lock date" value.  Is this possible in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

(Adding more characters here to pass Stack Overflow's minimum character requirement.)

Comment: A better question is, how to I extract an ETAG from a record so I can use it again when I update it using a different DataContext.

Comment: I asked this very question 2+ years ago and never received a response from anyone.  Any tips are appreciated:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/3746108/328397